# Unable to find root cause of ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net, windbg, sos

I'm investigating the cause of the huge amount of `ArgumentException` in an application (and I'm suspecting that its main reason for memory fragmentation/out of memory exception).
The problem is that I can't find where this exception is coming from.

I have memory dump of the problematic service but all I can see is that it happened on one of the threads and that it is related to reflection stuff, other than that it seems that I can't find the cause of the exception.

ArgumentException details:

```
Exception type:   System.ArgumentException
Message:          Missing parameter does not have a default value.
InnerException:   <none>
StackTrace (generated):
    SP       IP       Function
    0347D2F0 72B006F2 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(System.Object[], System.Reflection.Binder, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Signature)+0xc27c02
    0347D328 71EC0EDB mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+0x9b
    0347D35C 71EC0DD7 mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+0x37
    0347D390 71EC0D8E mscorlib_ni!System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)+0x3e

StackTraceString: <none>
HResult: 80070057
```

Output of `~#s; !clrstack`:

```
OS Thread Id: 0x524 (1)
Child SP       IP Call Site
033fcf00 7726a8fc [HelperMethodFrame: 033fcf00] 
033fcfb0 72b006f2 System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(System.Object[], System.Reflection.Binder, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Signature)
033fcfe8 71ec0edb System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
033fd01c 71ec0dd7 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
033fd050 71ec0d8e System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
033fda64 730eebe6 [DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame: 033fda64] 
033fda34 730eebe6 [GCFrame: 033fda34] 
033fda18 730eebe6 [GCFrame: 033fda18]
```

How to find out where this exception came from? It looks like its missing part of the stack trace.

Comment: You need to try debugging it.

Comment: @spodger  this happens on our production server and we don't see those on testing environment on our local machines.

Comment: What about `~#s; !clrstack`?

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 3):

According to the Microsoft documentation, The `PropertyInfo.GetValue()` method throws an `ArgumentException` when either of the following is true:

"The index array does not contain the type of arguments needed.

-or-

The property's get accessor is not found."

I would look for any calls in the source code that are calling `GetValue()` and inspect the arguments being passed into them.  One of the two scenarios outlined above is likely the culprit.

Comment: Good point @bryan-ponnwitz. Actually, I don't know why I haven't looked at msdn before. Thing is that I was looking at the .net source code and found this https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs,355. 
This line of code will throw if parameter default value is DBNull but that kida contradicts msdn source?